# 2-3 MBs Used When changing Image of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Every time I change the image of a `UIImageView`, there is about **2-3 MBs** added to the running memory as indicated by the left memory sidebar in Xcode. Here is my code to cycle through a couple images using one `UIImageView` in Xcode 5:

```
- (void)PlayThoseImages{
    if(CurrentImage < TotalNumOfImgaes){
        CurrentImage++ ;
        ImageName = @"Image  .png" ;

        NameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i",CurrentImageString] ;

        ImageName = [ImageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString: CurrentImageString] ;

        BackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ImageName] ;
        [self performSelector:@selector(PlayThoseImages) withObject:nil afterDelay:DelayInteger];
    }
    else{
        ImageName = nil ;
        CurrentImageString = nil ;
    }
}
```

The strings, ImageName and CurrentImageString are global NSStrings declared in the header, as are the integers.

The delayed loop runs as expected and the strings to change the name of the image displayed works perfectly, but why, ever time it projects a new image(loops once), is there an increase in memory of about **2-3 MBs**? I am using `ARC`.

Comment: it seems to me, you put the new image into the cache every time. the cache is emptied by iOS periodically, that is why you see the memory increasing only.

Comment: So when would I see the memory go down? How long does it take after a new image is loaded into the `UIImageView`?

Comment: good question. generally when iOS thinks the available memory is low. that is highly depends on the runtime environment.

Comment: if you are not keeping the object alive you should not worry about it, but you'd like to be a better memory-citizen, you have choice to decide how frequently you'd like to reload/reuse the same image again and again, that can defines whether the cache is the better way to load into it, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*imageNamed:* adds the image to the cache if you don't like the image to be cached use
*imageWithContentsOfFile:*

see: [UIImage class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)